# Android NDK Cross compilation issue in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, android-ndk

I am facing issue to get python working on Android Board.
I cross compiled python 2.7.14 successfully and copied binaries and lib onto the board and getting following error.

CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "python2.7": cannot locate symbol "nl_langinfo" referenced by "/system/bin/python2.7"...
Aborted

I used ndk version16b for cross compilation.
any help and idea shall be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**nl_langinfo()** was introduced to Android at API 26. If your board runs an older version of Android, you should recompile python, setting the **ANDROID_API** to match your version.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am running Android 7 on board. The problem scenario is when I am compiling python with ndk10e with api 21 then its working fine but without some important package like zlib. and when I am compiling python with ndk16 then its compiling zlib but while running its throwing error "cannot locate symbol "nl_langinfo" referenced by "/system/bin/python2.7"... Aborted "

Comment: You can compile with ndk r16 for API 21 or even API 24.